# Duo-tone Effect in Blender's Compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

How can I make a duo-tone effect shown on this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really only need to use a color ramp node, but I have added some math nodes to control the contrast. Instead of these you could use a Color Curve node.

[image: duotone]

Comment: Can you send me the close-up of the node setup?

Comment: If you click on the image it will download to its own browser page which you can zoom into ;-)